# Google Apps Script not showing up when signed out

Tags: google-apps-script, google-visualization, google-sites

I am trying to put an interactive map from GeoCharts on my website using Google Apps Script. The maps show up when I am signed into my Google account but they do not show up when I am signed off. How can I fix this?

Here is the `doGet` I use and `prate` is an HTML file in the project. I then deploy the project as a web app and choose

> Execute the app as: 'Me'
>
> Who has access to the app: "Anyone'

```
function doGet() {
 return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('prate').setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
 }
```

I don't get an error on the page when I am logged out, it just does not show up. Here is the link to the page: https://sites.google.com/site/christinegbraun/data

Comment: You can't update with the new setting, you must publish a new version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you did add in your website the `/exec` not the `/dev`
Also make sure everyone can access the app by choosing in settings

**Who has access to the app**: `anyone, even anonymous`

Comment: We'll see what Christine says, but I think you've got the answer with the access setting. Your answer would be improved with a brief explanation of the difference between "anyone" and "anyone, even anonymous", and how that explains the behavior that she has seen.

Comment: @niwox Yes changing it to "anyone, even anonymous" worked but now it is showing a banner at the top of the script which is not great looking. I found this discussion online [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=522) with some code in the fourth comment but it did not work. The error was that the "attribute add does not exits for object HtmlOutput" Any ideas how to get rid of this or is even something I could get rid of?

Comment: Sorry @Mogsdad, will do. Clearly I'm new :)